# Building a Chance Mixin in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I am working on a ChanceJS [mixin](http://chancejs.com/helpers/mixin.html) that I plan to distribute via npm.

I am having issues trying to get the correct Interface and Typings defined.

Example of the package: // index.ts

```
import * as Chance from 'chance';

export interface ITime {
  time(): string;
}

function time() {
  const h = chance.hour({ twentyfour: true });
  const m = chance.minute();
  return `${h}:${m}`;
};

export const time: ITime = {
  time,
};
```

Example of how someone would consume it:

```
import * as Chance from 'chance';
import { time } from 'chance-time';

const chance = new Chance();
chance.mixin(time);

chance.time()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error:(12, 14) TS2345: Argument of type 'ITime' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MixinDescriptor'.
Index signature is missing in type 'ITime'.
Error:(25, 26) TS2339: Property 'time' does not exist on type 'Chance'.
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the [DefinitelyTyped definitions for ChanceJS](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b0839e0bf0/types/chance/index.d.ts) don't really support what you're trying to do.  The ideal fix for this would be to change those typings, but assuming you don't want to do that, type assertions will be your friend.

I don't have ChanceJS installed, so you might need to alter the following code (namespaces etc) to get it working:

```
const chance = new Chance() as Chance.Chance & ITime;
chance.mixin(time as any); // no error
chance.time(); // no error now I hope
```

In the first line, the idea is that `chance` will end up becoming both a `Chance` and an `ITime`, since that's what the mixin function does.  This will allow the `chance.time()` line to compile without errors.

In the second line, you are just suppressing the "index signature missing" error.  There are other ways around it, but the gist of it is that since `ITime` is an interface without an index signature, you can't assign it to an interface with an index signature like `MixinDescriptor`.  This is a [known and currently intended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) behavior.  The easiest way to deal with it might be to change `ITime` from an `interface` to a `type`.

Finally, your mixin might need fixin', since your `time()` function implementation refers to a variable named `chance` which doesn't seem to be defined.  I imagine the code throws an error at runtime, but maybe you haven't included all the relevant code or it's just an example.  Taking the code at face value, maybe instead of `chance` you should use `this` (and keep TypeScript happy by using a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) with type `Chance`)?  Like

```
function time(this: Chance.Chance) {
  const h = this.hour({ twentyfour: true });
  const m = this.minute();
  return `${h}:${m}`;
};
```

Anyway, that's the closest I can give to an answer without installing ChanceJS.  Hope it gets you pointed in the right direction.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this great response. I agree the best solution would be to update the typings, but I am not too sure where the typeings needs to be changed to fix this. I am still learning TypeScript, the way I learn is by using it every day and building projects in it.

That being said, your solution fixed a lot of the compile errors. Now the only thing I am only getting `Error:(11, 32) TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Chance' as a type.`

I am assuming this is due to how the typings are built.

Comment: Maybe it's `Chance.Chance`?  There's a namespace named `Chance` with an interface named `Chance` inside it.  What type do you see when you inspect an object you create with `new Chance()`?  It's hard for me to debug unless I install that library and its typings, which I am not in the position to do right now.

Comment: `Chance.Chance` fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The way I have implemented this is as follows. My mixins use a common code base to generate mocks, so I will include it here.

Define common mixins interface, ignore this if you are not going to use it.

```
interface Mock_I<T> {
  id?: number
  depth?: number
  models?: string[]
  ensure?: string[]
  skip?: string[]
  data?: T
}
```

Define options for each mixin:

```
// example of a model that uses this mock
interface ProfileModelBasedMockParamsI extends Mock_I<ProfileModel> {
  notation?: string // let's just say time has this optional param
}

// simple as question asked
interface TimeMockParamsI {
  notation?: string // let's just say time has this optional param
}
```

Now extend chance with your mixins and create a new interface that you use instead of the Chance.Chance interface:

```
interface ChanceMixins extends Chance.Chance {
  time(options: TimeMockParamsI): any
  // ... more mixins here as needed
}
```

Then finally use it (do `yarn add -D @types/chance` to add chance types if you haven't already):

```
import Chance from 'chance';
const chance = new Chance() as Chance.Chance & ChanceMixins;

chance.time(); // should work with no issues
chance.time('24'); // should work with no issues
```